# How can I tie a WPF Command to a MouseEnter event?

Tags: wpf, command, mouseenter

I need to tie a WPF-Command to the MouseEnter event of a Stackpanel. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the attached behavior pattern. There are several implementations, a good one is available here : http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/

Comment: I was hoping for a much more built-in support for that in WPF but this seems like quite a neat way of solving it.

Comment: Thanks man, I did not think that article it was linking to was what you were referring to =P