# Getting the listBoxItem on focus

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Is there a way on a typical listBox, to determine which listBoxItem is currently focused on?
I am talking about the state before selection, more like the mouse-over event.

I tried the `MouseEnter` and `Focus` events, but the problem is, that I found no way to determine which item called those events.

Answer (score 1):

You should use SelectedIndex or SelectedItem

Comment: Doesn't work. SelectedIndex is still -1 and SelectedItem is null

Answer (score 0):

You'd need something more elaborate...

See this one for an 'event based' solution - though `I wouldn't recommend that (unless a fast fix or very specific) as it 'ties' your code, you should keep MVVM as much as possible`...

[ListBox Mouse Over - How to get the item](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/36ddd797-9213-4dc2-a6ef-4cea466be5a5/)

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">  
        <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseEnter" /> 
    </Style> 
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

And to fix that to work w/ MVVM (`i.e. you need to bind that event as a command into your view-model ICommand` - you'd need an attached property of a sort - e.g (just a fast search will get you many)...

[How can I tie a WPF Command to a MouseEnter event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537158/how-can-i-tie-a-wpf-command-to-a-mouseenter-event)
[How can I execute a command binding on MouseEnter of a StackPanel in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152389/how-can-i-execute-a-command-binding-on-mouseenter-of-a-stackpanel-in-wpf)
[WPF – Execute button command on MouseOver](http://sblanco.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/execute-button-command-on-mouseover/)

Then bind that `attached property` to your view-model property - you'll get as 'hovered item' changes - and then you can do the rest - even set / expose your own 'HoveredItem' property (it's how I'd do it - connect all together and make instead of command wire directly to that hoevered property or something. This is a pseudo code fast, hope it helps.